# How to prevent to lockout from vpn server?

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, wireguard

I have a wireguard server on VPS, I am able to connect through ssh. It has to put on  port forward ssh command to wireguard client.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.x:22; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j MASQUERADE
```

After this port forward command I am not able to connect to wireguard server from any connection, Either lan or Wan.

How to avoid this?

Comment: sorry, what's the purpose of that? can you connect to wireguard before you run that?

Comment: @JaromandaX  I want to connect to check or update wireguard server. Either I am connected to vps or not. LAN or WAN from any connection.